# context menu "Open with IDLE" for Python .py files blown away

Tags: python, contextmenu, menuitem, python-idle

Somehow managed to blow this away, and can't figure out how to get it back
Tried un- and re-installing Python 3, but that didn't do it.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 3):

By default the python installation setup the actions on a .py file to be "Open" and "Edit with Idle".

Those settings are stored in the Windows registry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py`

If you change those settings (by error or not), windows shall create a new entry in the registry with your new settings. This entry is located in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py
```

This new entry overrides the default behaviour.

So to restore the default behaviour just delete the entry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py
```

WARNING: As you probably know, messing with the registry is dangerous for your Windows configuration. Be sure to act carefully and don't delete or change anything in the registry that could make Windows unusable

Comment: Please use the code format for the path as they look much more legible that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows is the OS in use here, could you just right click and choose idle as the default program via the "open with" option in the menu?

And because I totally hated using IDLE I always recommend eclipse and pydev to people who are using IDLE.  Eclipse and pydev making coding a lot more fun.

I use everything here except the ANT part.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecant/

Comment: Let's not jump the gun: IDLE is simple and does the job, particularly if you're getting started with Python. A full IDE is a daunting thing to set up and use, and if you're only working on small projects, the benefit is minimal.

Comment: @Thomas K  I agree somewhat, but simple things like copy and paste in IDLE seem to be sub par.  Also, even when doing simple things when learning python can be easier if you have your code completion explaining what choices you have and what each will do every time you hit that "." key.  Yeah, maybe it can be daunting, but IBM did a pretty good job in that link of making it pretty straightforward.  It's all opinion, but I sure am glad I ditched IDLE when I was learning.

Comment: Well, I don't have any trouble copying and pasting in IDLE, and it even does code completion and auto indenting for me. But even if it is problematic, I maintain that the complexity of a full IDE (and plugin) is offputting for newcomers. A good alternative would be a decent text editor, like Notepad ++ (well, I hear it's good; I haven't used it myself).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I haven't used IDLE in a while.  It seems like either doing ctrl + c or right clicking didn't behave as copying normally would.  It will get the job done, I just don't prefer it.

Comment: I used to be able to Open with, Now I can't.  That's the problem!  The point is not to use something else, the point is to be able to get to IDLE easily (even though IDLE is not the greatest).

Comment: Notice that nothing listed here answers my question . . .

Comment: Read the first paragraph.  Can you use the open with option in the menu?  That is the first thing I typed, then I made my other suggestion.  Please read my first paragraph, will that work for you?  Please notice that the first thing here might answer your question.

Comment: I was trying to explain that's exactly what got blown away.  I CAN'T open it by right-clicking and choosing open with, that's the part that's missing.

Comment: When I right-click and choose Open with, it allows me to select a browser or WordPad.  When I select "Choose Default Program" and try to find Idle, none of the appropriate candidates seem to work.  I can't figure out which program should be set up to run.